# How to implement timers in Omnet++?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I need to implement timer in Omnet++.
Scenario : There are 2 nodes(Say A and B). Node A sends a msg to node B. Then a timer need to be started. If it doesnot receive any msg from node B within a specific period, the connection should end.

Comment: I wonder how beneficial the  C++ tag is to this question. It attracts a lot of extra eyes to the question, but relatively few will be able to help you because they aren't familiar, or familiar enough, with omnet.

Answer (score 4):

In `OMNeT++` timer is a message that is scheduled to trigger in the future in that module using `scheduleAt()`. That message is called "selfmessage" and it is used to implement "timer".
When the [selfmessage](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:self-messages) occurs, `handleMessage()` is called - just like for any other message.
In short: to implement selfmessage one should:

1. Declare and then create an instance of `cMessage`.
2. Schedule that message using:

`scheduleAt(simTime() + somePeriod, someMessage)`
where `simTime()` returns current simulation time.

3. In `handleMessage()` recognize that selfmessage, for example using [`isSelfMessage()`](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cMessage.html#ad0a6ef65ee891c10fc9ad126768b3941), and call desired code.

Moreover, take a look at TicToc examples: [TicToc doumentation - 3.6 Modeling processing delay](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part3/#36-modeling-processing-delay)