# How to send a message after a defined time?

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins, sumo

Upon receiving a message, I want to broadcast it after a defined waiting time.

For example when `node[8]` receives the message `wsm` at time `t=109s`, it rebroadcasts it at a defined time `T`, so I used:

```
scheduleAt(simTime()+T,wsm->dup());
```

as a result I had from `t=109s`, it broadcasts a message after each second.

So I tried with this method:

```
scheduleAt(Ts, wsm->dup()); // Ts=109+T
```

It gives me this error at runtime:

```
Cannot schedule message (veins::Mwsm) to the past, 
t=0 -- in module (DissApp) Net.node[8].appl (id=56), 
at t=109.000243213075s, event #176
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Is this relevant? [Timer-based sending of message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248628/timer-based-sending-of-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says that a message is tried to schedule in the past: in t=109 s the message is scheduled for t=0 (what is impossible).
If you use `scheduleAt(Ts, wsm->dup());` be sure that Ts is larger than current simulation time.

Comment: The problem is solved, I had a problem calculating the waiting time, it did not take the calculated value so it took 0 by default. Thanks very much